# Are parameters of self reference only available in the specific trait?

Tags: scala

I would like to build a case class `DataObject`.

```
case class DataObject(parameter: Double)
```

I want to be able to extend this if necessary with the functionality to call a function. For that I want to be able to extend it with a trait `DataObjectFunctionable` to make it functionable. This functionality should only be assignable to `DataObject` because it only makes sense there.

```
trait DataObjectFunctionable {
  this: DataObject =>
  def unimportantfunction(): Double = parameter + 1
  protected val aFunction: AFunction
}
```

The exact implementation shall be defined later, thus I keep the Function abstract. Since the extra functionality shall only be a trait for `DataObject` and a `DataObject` with the functionality would be `DataObjectFunctionable`, I give `DataObjectFunctionable` as input type for the function.

```
trait AFunction {
    def value(in: DataObjectFunctionable)
}
```

Now I am going to define my concrete Function.This is all good and well, until I want to excess the inputs parameters.

```
object MyFunction extends AFunction {
    def value(in: DataObjectFunctionable) = in.parameter + 2
}
```

Now I am told that `in.parameter` cannot be resolved. Why is that? `this: DataObject =>` makes sure that `DataObject`'s members are also available inside `DataObjectFunctionable` (as seen with `unimportantfunction`). Why is it that though this is the case, I don't have `parameter` at my disposal in `MyFunction`? Is it just language design or am I doing something wrong?

What should I do instead? I found that

```
trait DataObjectFunctionable extends DataObject {
  this: DataObject =>
  def unimportantfunction(): Double = parameter + 1
  protected val aFunction: AFunction
}
```

solves the issue, but is this really the way to go?

As far as I understand, `trait DataObjectFunctionable extends DataObject` means "the trait `DataObjectFunctionable` can only be extended by an `DataObject` or a subclass of it". However, as far as I understand `this: DataObject =>` means the same... Maybe there is a misunderstanding here that led to my issue.

---

By the way, this is what I hoped for:

```
val myObject1 = new DataObject(parameter = 5) extends DataObjectFunctionable {
    override protected val aFunction: AFunction = MyFunction
  }
val myObject2 = new DataObject(parameter = 5)
myObject1.value // returns 5
myObject2.value // that should not be possible, since myObject2 does not get the functionality. I want this to throw a compiler error
```

Comment: Could you define "returns error"?

Comment: @Reactormonk: done. edited question.

Comment: Somehow that doesn't line up - where do you attach `value` to `DataObject`?

Comment: Also, the idea of sometimes attaching functionality to a class sounds like a Typeclass to me - maybe that might work better?

Answer (score 1):

Self-reference is akin to "private inheritance". 
If you don't want the inherited parameters to be "private" to the trait, why don't you make it inherit from `DataObject` rather than self-reference it?

Alternatively, you can "export" the self-referenced parameter from the trait with something like `def param = parameter`.

Also, a word of caution: don't extend case classes, not even with traits. It is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I think the "private inheritance" is the right keyword here. Your first paragraph was also my idea (see question). Isn't it a little weird that `DataObject` is often instanciated with `DataObjectFunctionable` (thus inherits it) and `DataObjectFunctionable` extends `DataObject` (thus inherits it vice-versa)?

Comment: I think I don't quite understand the difference between `traits extending classes` and `trait self reference`. But I probably should as a different question for that.

Comment: `DataObject` does not inherit from `DataObjectFunctionable`. When you say it is "often instantiated with it", what it really means, that you often create other classes (perhaps, anonymous), that inherit from _both_ `DataObject` and `DataObjectFunctionable`. That doesn't make the former inherit fro the latter in any way.

Comment: Maybe, I am not so firm with the Scala lingo (and Scala itself). In Java you inherit (extend) or implement. I meant `val a = new DataObject(...) with DataObjectFunctionable`

Comment: Yes. This creates an instance of an anonymous class, that extends `DataObject` and "implements" (also extends really) `DataObjectFunctionable`

Comment: `DataObject` is a normal class - what do you mean by anonymous?